# Lambda couldn’t copy Spawn and Actions in cocos2d?

Tags: lambda, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to run a Spawn and a Scale action within a lambda but Lambda doesn't copy theirs value at all. In the below code, I have a defined `onSelectedSpawn`, which is a Spawn. `mSetting` and `mFamilyTV` are MenuItemImage. what I am doing wrong? Your help is very much appreciated.

```
auto fadeIn = FadeTo::create(0.5f, 255);
auto scaleIn = ScaleBy::create(0.5f, 1.4f);
auto onSelectedSpawn = Spawn::createWithTwoActions(fadeIn, scaleIn);

// This run without any problem
mSetting->runAction(onSelectedSpawn); 
mFamilyTV = MenuItemImage::create("en_block5.png", "en_block5_hover.png",
        [=](cocos2d::Ref* pSender){

      //Running Spawn makes app crashed because the lambda couldn't copy onSelectedSpawn's value
    mFamilyTV->runAction(onSelectedSpawn);
      //Running Scale action make app crashed too. It also doesn't copy scaleIn at all
        mFamilyTV->runAction(scaleIn);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use local variable in lambda you have pass it explicitly. Also you have to retain animations, because they'll be released from memory.

```
auto fadeIn = FadeTo::create(0.5f, 255);
auto scaleIn = ScaleBy::create(0.5f, 1.4f);
scaleIn->retain();
auto onSelectedSpawn = Spawn::createWithTwoActions(fadeIn, scaleIn);
onSelectedSpawn->retain();

// This run without any problem
mSetting->runAction(onSelectedSpawn); 
mFamilyTV = MenuItemImage::create("en_block5.png", "en_block5_hover.png",
        [&, scaleIn, onSelectedSpawn](cocos2d::Ref* pSender){

        //this will only work once, next time you have to clone action
        mFamilyTV->runAction(onSelectedSpawn->clone());
        mFamilyTV->runAction(scaleIn->clone());
});

//somewhere where you no longer need these animations, for example when leaving a scene:
scaleIn->release();
onSelectedSpawn->release();
```

I think this solution is a bit too painful, because you have to pass actions to lambda and remember about retain/release and clone. 
The easiest way to do this will be to create special function, which create these animations in place:

```
mFamilyTV = MenuItemImage::create("en_block5.png", "en_block5_hover.png",
        [&](cocos2d::Ref* pSender){

        mFamilyTV->runAction(createOnSelectedSpawn());
        mFamilyTV->runAction(createScaleIn());
});

ActionInterval* HelloWorld::createScaleIn(){
    return ScaleBy::create(0.5f, 1.4f);
}

ActionInterval* HelloWorld::createOnSelectedSpawn(){
    auto fadeIn = FadeTo::create(0.5f, 255);
    auto scaleIn = createScaleIn();
    return Spawn::createWithTwoActions(fadeIn, scaleIn);
}
```

Comment: Your advice works likes a charm. Thanks a lot, you saved my day. Wish I could up-vote your reply 100 times. :)